# which IVR framework is suitable in UAE region?

Tags: twilio, asterisk, watson, ivr

We want to build IVR based application for a client in UAE.

The user can ask a query and a voice enabled bot can resolve the query on the other end.

If anyone knows suitable framework for this could be a big help.

Thank you

Comment: None. UAE block voip, work only via openvpn or other tuunnel.

Comment: is ngrok will be suitable?  @arheops

Answer (score 0):

If you whish to build a phone service based on asterisk, you can try voximal, it's a VoiceXML framework, with TTS and STT.

Comment: I think Voximal is the only one (and it can use Chatbots too to qualify answer requests), if any one have more references... ?

Comment: how about twilio ?

Comment: Twilio is more than an IVR framework, it's a turnkey solution, where you pay not for hosting or licenses, but for phone minutes (they hosts your numbers). I think it can do the job too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build an IVR you can use any SIP framework with media capabilities. You can check Adhearsion framework for reference.

Comment: With Voximal you can connect any SIP provider. It runs over an Asterisk.